# How do I iterate over all the rows in my sheet to find match?

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a script with google appscript to

- read files in a folder
- parse the name of the file in the folder
- check if that name already exists in the sheet
- if not add that to the list
- if it does exist then check another column to see if an email is sent
- if yes do nothing if no send the email.

I have tried 
index of
,for loop to iterate over range.getValues()
None of them work properly as expected.
The data is of length 3.

```
function myFunction() {
  getFileNameFromFolders('1TcR5oUKwH9hUG9xHBA6HuXQOr40etS5z');
}

function getFileNameFromFolders(folderID) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var agentDetails = fileName.split("-");
    var agentID = agentDetails[0];
    var fileType = agentDetails[1];
    var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
    var fileDate = agentDetails[2];
    locateAgent(agentID, fileType, fileDate, fileUrl, fileName);
  }
}

function locateAgent(agentID, fileType, fileDate, url, uniqueKey) {
  Logger.log('locating ' + uniqueKey);
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl());
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 6)
  var data = range.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i][5] == uniqueKey) {
      Logger.log('yes');
      break;
    }
    else { Logger.log('no');
    var newRange = sheet.appendRow([agentID,fileType, fileDate, url, 'r', uniqueKey]);}
  }
}

function sendEmails(email, fileUrl) {
  var asPDF = DriveApp.getFileById(getIdFromUrl(fileUrl));
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'test-email-with-agent-stuff-thing-i-dont-know-the-name', 'you should recieve a file named AID-2 as you are registered as 2', {
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script from DOER',
    attachments: asPDF.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
  });
}

function getIdFromUrl(url) {
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}$/);
}
```

The loop adds to the list even though it exists. I may be getting the concept. If you have any other way I can do this, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Look at the range you are inspecting for the existing details..... It can never have any values in it, even though it has a non-zero row count.

Comment: this is the range I initially had `var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can implement a boolean variable which will be set to true if uniqueKey exists alredy

Modify your code as following:

```
function locateAgent(agentID, fileType, fileDate, url, uniqueKey) {
  Logger.log('locating ' + uniqueKey);
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl());
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 6)
  var data = range.getValues();
 var exists=false;
  for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i][5] == uniqueKey){
      exists=true;
      var row=i;
      break;
    }
 }
  if(exists==false){
    Logger.log('it does not exist yet');
    var insertRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 6); 
    //adapt according to your needs:
    insertRange.setValues([[agentID],[fileType],[fileDate],[url],[],[uniqueKey]]);
  }else{
   //implement here your statement to check status column, e.g.:
    if(data[row][status column]!="Sent"){
          sendEmails(...);
     }
  } 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I feel silly for not thinking of using a bool. Thank you.!!!!!!!!!

Comment: is there any way i can make it faster  ?

Comment: It might be faster if use `indexOf()` instead of a `for` loop. For this, map the contents of column 6 to an 1-D array and proceed as before: `if(array.indexOf(uniqueKey)>-1){exists=true;...}`

Comment: yes. I went ahead and implemented the indexof. Thanks for the help.